# removing initialisation logs while using selenium and phantom js

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless

i am unable to remove [initialisation logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNxdM.png)  getting displayed while using selenium and phantom js

Below is the code i have used for headless testing

```
DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    String[] phantomArgs = new String[] { "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE" };
    dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
    PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: IMO, These are the minimum logs we need to see to confirm that `PhantomJSDriver` is invoked properly and is working. Thanks

Comment: @ DebanjanB. so according to you these initialisation logs cannot be removed